# kendu ui grid after server update cells stay marked as "dirty"

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

i based this code on kendu grid ui code demo.
when ever i add a new record, it gets sent to the server side (c# handler)
and from there i convert json to object.. and so on.
the operation is successful and the request that kendu made is done with status code 200.
but for some reason the cells that were changed are still marked as "dirty" .
as a result of this any new row is sent with the first attempt since it thinks it needs to be sent again. here is my code:

```
 jQuery("#getallDataBTN").click(
        function () {
            $("#grid").kendoGrid({
                dataSource: {
                    transport: {
                        read: {
                            url: "/WallEHandler.ashx?command=getallPermissions",
                            dataType: "json"
                        },
                        create: {
                            url: "/WallEHandler.ashx?command=addPermission",
                            dataType: "json",
                            type:"post"
                        },
                        update: {
                          //  url: "/WallEHandler.ashx?command=editPermission",
                          //  dataType: "jsonp"
                        },
                        parameterMap: function (options, operation) {
                            if (operation !== "read" && options.models) {
                                return { models: kendo.stringify(options.models) };
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    schema: {
                        model: {
                            id:"Method",
                            fields: {
                                Method: { type: "string" , validation: { required: true }},
                                ServiceType: { type: "string" ,validation: { required: true }},
                                Role: { type: "string" ,validation: { required: true }},
                                Permission: { type: "string" ,validation: { required: true }},
                                ExtendedData: { type: "string" }
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    pageSize: 100,
                    batch: true,
                },
                height:850,
                scrollable: true,
                sortable: true,
                filterable: true,
                pageable: {
                    input: true,
                    numeric: false
                },
                columns: [
                    "Method",
                     "ServiceType",
                     "Role",
                     { field: "Permission", editor: categoryDropDownEditor },
                     "ExtendedData"
                ],

                navigatable: true,
                toolbar: ["create", "save", "cancel"],
                editable: true
                //selectable: "row",
                //save: function(e)
              //  {
                  //alert("Save");
               // }
            });
        }
        );
```

is there maybe somthing i need to return from the server to tell the grid that it was successful?

thanks for any help

Comment: is there a reason why the update parameters are commented out in your example?

Comment: yea, im currently not using them (server side does not support yet). my issue is with create.

Answer (score 0):

i figured it out, it seems that the response of a successful request must return the same object as sent. (must be some sort of inside validation by kendu).

c#:

```
 Response.Write(context.Request.Form["models"]);
```